# extjs create dual rows

Tags: extjs, grid, rows, extjs4.1

tell me please how I can create dual rows in grid like this:

In ext JS I have not found such an example

[image: I make it in gimp]

Comment: Your question is confusing. "Dual rows" to me, means two rows. In your picture I see a grid with four rows, but I don't think you are trying to ask how to create more than one row in a grid. Are you asking about cell editing in a grid? That seems to be the feature of the image you posted.

Comment: I think he means same style for row #1 and #2, different for #3 and #4 and so on

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which version of ExtJs you're using but I think `getRowClass` method is available in 3 and 4.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass

You can define any logic you need inside this handler. In your case you would need to return one class for rows 1, 2, 5, 6 etc... and second class for 3, 4, 7, 8 etc.